# How to properly setup a polymorphic model using Sequelize and GraphQL

Tags: sequelize.js, graphql

I am currently trying to learn React by developing a meal planner app for myself.  Coming from a traditional business programming world I have decided on using MySQL as a backend, and Sequelize/GraphQL as my data interface.

I have a data model that goes as follows:
-Users have Meals
-Meals have the properties of day, type (breakfast, lunch, etc) and "MealItems"
-MealItems can be either a FoodItem or a Recipe
-Recipes are basically a collection of FoodItems

I implemented that idea with this data schema (really quick mockup done in Access): [Meal Planner Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjzvx.png)

I have managed to code up a Sequelize model that creates the tables and constraints exactly how I want.  I used the n:m association example from the official Sequelize documentation to create the MealItems lookup table that should allow for the model to dynamically return either a FoodItem or Recipe, based on the scope ("ItemType").  (But I don't know if I did that part correctly as I can't manage to actually pull the data through anything other than raw SQL queries.)

The full source code for my project can be found here: (the relevant data components are under './src/data')
https://github.com/philspins/NourishMe

Sequelize model:

```
//
// Model definitions
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
import DataType from "sequelize";
import Model from "../sequelize";

const FoodItem = Model.define("FoodItem",
{

    Name: { type: DataType.STRING(100) },
    Quantity: { type: DataType.STRING(32) },
    Weight: { type: DataType.INTEGER },
    Calories: { type: DataType.INTEGER },
    Protein: { type: DataType.DOUBLE },
    Carbs: { type: DataType.DOUBLE },
    Fat: { type: DataType.DOUBLE },
    Fibre: { type: DataType.DOUBLE },
    ImageURL: { type: DataType.TEXT }
});

const Recipe = Model.define("Recipe",
{
    Name: { type: DataType.STRING(100) },
    Instructions: { type: DataType.TEXT },
    ImageURL: { type: DataType.TEXT }
});

const Ingredient = Model.define("Ingredient");

const Meal = Model.define("Meal",
{
    Day: { type: DataType.DATE }
});

const MealType = Model.define("MealType",
{
    Name: { type: DataType.STRING(100) }
});

const MealItem = Model.define("MealItem",
{
    id: {type: DataType.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    ItemType: { type: DataType.STRING(100) },
    ItemID: { type: DataType.STRING(100) },
    Quantity: { type: DataType.DOUBLE }
},
{
    instanceMethods: {
        getItem: function() {
            return this["get" + this.get("ItemType").substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + this.get("ItemType").substr(1)]();
        }
    }
});

//
// Recipe and FoodItem relations
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Recipe.FoodItems = Recipe.belongsToMany(FoodItem, {
    through: Ingredient,
    as: "FoodItems"
});
FoodItem.Recipes = FoodItem.belongsToMany(Recipe, {
    through: Ingredient,
    as: "Recipes"
});


//
// Meals relationships with Recipe and FoodItem
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Meal.belongsToMany(Recipe, {
    through: MealItem,
    foreignKey: "ItemID",
    constraints: false,
    scope: {
        ItemType: "Recipe"
    }
});
Recipe.belongsToMany(Meal, {
    through: MealItem,
    foreignKey: "ItemID",
    constraints: false,
    as: "Recipe"
});
Meal.belongsToMany(FoodItem, {
    through: MealItem,
    foreignKey: "ItemID",
    constraints: false,
    scope: {
        ItemType: "FoodItem"
    }
});
FoodItem.belongsToMany(Meal, {
    through: MealItem,
    foreignKey: "ItemID",
    constraints: false,
    as: "FoodItem"
});


//
// Other Meal relationships
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Meal.MealItems = Meal.hasMany(MealItem, {foreignKey: {allowNull: false}, onDelete: "CASCADE"});
Meal.User = User.hasMany(Meal, {foreignKey: {allowNull: false}, onDelete: "CASCADE"});
Meal.MealType = MealType.hasMany(Meal, {foreignKey: {allowNull: false}, onDelete: "CASCADE"});
```

I have GraphQL types and queries setup to return all data except for Meal.  I can not get it to return anything except for the values that are actually in the MealItem table.  I was able to link up FoodItem to Recipe no problem, and retrieve a JSON package that has FoodItems embedded in Recipes, but can't figure out how to do the same thing with MealItems.  This is the model as I have it working now: [Visualization of GraphQL model as it is][3]
But I would like to have Meals be able to have either FoodItems or Recipes embedded in the output rather than MealItems.

And this is my GraphQL code, as I have it working:

```
import {GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLList,
    GraphQLNonNull,
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLString} from "graphql";
import {resolver, attributeFields} from "graphql-sequelize";
import {Meal, 
    Recipe, 
    FoodItem as 
    FoodModel, 
    MealItem as MealItemModel} from "../models";

const FoodType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "FoodItem",
    fields: attributeFields(FoodModel),
    resolve: resolver(FoodModel)
});

const RecipeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Recipe",
    fields: {
        id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
        Name: { type: GraphQLString },
        Instructions: { type: GraphQLString },
        ImageURL: { type: GraphQLString },
        Ingredients: {
            type: new GraphQLList(FoodType),
            resolve: resolver(Recipe.FoodItems) }
    }
});

const MealTypeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "MealType",
    fields: attributeFields(MealType)
});

const MealItemType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "MealItem",
    fields: attributeFields(MealItemModel),
    resolve: resolver(MealItemModel)
});

const MealType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Meal",
    fields: {
        id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
        Day: { type: DateType },
        UserId: { type: GraphQLID },
        MealTypeId: { type: GraphQLID },
        MealItems: {
            type: new GraphQLList(MealItemType),
            resolve: resolver(Meal.MealItems)
        }
    }
});

const Meals = {
    type: new GraphQLList(MealType),
    resolve: resolver(Meal)
};

const schema = new Schema({
    query: new ObjectType({
        name: "Root",
        fields: {
            Meals
        }
    })
});
```

What I *think* I need to do, in order to get the MealType to dynamically return either a FoodType or RecipeType instead of MealItemType, is something along the lines of this.  But this is what I can't get to work, and is the cause of this extremely lengthy question.

```
function resolveMealItemType(value){
    if(value.ItemType == "Recipe"){return RecipeType;}else{return FoodType;}
}

const MealItemType = new GraphQLUnionType({
    name: "MealItem",
    types: [RecipeType, FoodType],
    resolveType: resolveMealItemType
});

const MealType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Meal",
    fields: {
        id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
        Day: { type: DateType },
        UserId: { type: GraphQLID },
        MealTypeId: { type: GraphQLID },
        MealItems: {
            type: new GraphQLList(MealItemType),
            resolve: resolver(Meal.MealItems)
        }
    }
});
```

Current query, and output:

```
{
  Meal {
    Day
    MealTypeId
    UserId
    MealItems {
      ItemType
      ItemID
    }
  }
}

{
  "data": {
    "Meal": {
      "Day": "2017-02-07T16:18:47.000Z",
      "MealTypeId": "1",
      "UserId": "1",
      "MealItems": [
        {
          "ItemType": "Recipe",
          "ItemID": 1
        },
        {
          "ItemType": "FoodItem",
          "ItemID": 25
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Desired query, and output:

```
{
  Meal {
    Day
    MealTypeId
    UserId
    MealItems {
      ... on FoodItem {
        Name
        Quantity
        Weight
        Calories
        Carbs
        Protein
        Fat
        Fibre
      }
      ... on Recipe {
        Name
        Instructions
        Ingredients {
          Name
          Quantity
          Weight
          Calories
          Carbs
          Protein
          Fat
          Fibre
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


{
  "data": {
    "Meal": {
      "Day": "2017-02-07T15:30:10.000Z",
      "MealTypeId": "1",
      "UserId": "1",
      "MealItems": [
        {
          "Name": "Fish, Halibut, Pacific",
          "Quantity": "4 oz uncooked",
          "Weight": 113,
          "Calories": 124,
          "Carbs": 0,
          "Protein": 24,
          "Fat": 3,
          "Fibre": 0
        },
        {
          "Name": "Test Recipe 1",
          "Instructions": "Recipe instructions go here...",
          "Ingredients": [
            {
              "Name": "Fish, Halibut, Pacific",
              "Quantity": "4 oz uncooked",
              "Weight": 113,
              "Calories": 124,
              "Carbs": 0,
              "Protein": 24,
              "Fat": 3,
              "Fibre": 0
            },
            {
              "Name": "Sardines (herring), canned in olive oil",
              "Quantity": "1 can (3.2 oz)",
              "Weight": 91,
              "Calories": 191,
              "Carbs": 0,
              "Protein": 23,
              "Fat": 11,
              "Fibre": 0
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: @iwasrobbed no, the best I could get it to work was like this: `{
  Meals{
    Day
    MealType {
      Name
    }
    User {
      login
    }
    FoodItems {
        Name
        Quantity
        Weight
        Calories
        Carbs
        Protein
        Fat
        Fibre
      }
      Recipes {
        Name
        Instructions
        Ingredients {
          Name
          Quantity
          Weight
          Calories
          Carbs
          Protein
          Fat
          Fibre
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

Comment: Thanks for the source at least; it helped me set up the initial polymorphic association

Comment: @iwasrobbed no worries, good luck figuring it out!  I'd love to see the result if you get it working.

Answer (score 5):

Don't set a key `resolver` directly inside a `GraphQLObjectType`:

```
...
const FoodType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "FoodItem",
    fields: attributeFields(FoodModel),
    resolve: resolver(FoodModel), // <--- this is wrong, it won't be used
    // Only set resolvers inside fields, not on the root of the object
});
...
```

---

Then you were right about using the `GraphQLUnionType`.
But in the resolve function of the `MealType`, you should return a **merged array of FoodItems and Recipes** and not entries of the `MealItems` table. You are saying with the union "I am returning a List of either FoodItem or Recipe", so this is what you should do.

So,

```
const MealType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    ...
    fields: {
        ...
        MealItems: {
            type: new GraphQLList(MealItemType),
            resolve: (meal, args, context) => {
                return Promise.all([
                    Meal.getFoodItems(), // pseudo-code
                    Meal.getRecipes(), // pseudo-code
                ])
                .then(([ foodItems, recipes ]) => foodItems.concat(recipes));
            },
        },
        ...
    },
});
```

Comment: Getting closer, but when I use Meal.get...() I receive this error: `"TypeError: _models.Meal.getFoodItems is not a function at resolve (/var/www/html/nourish/src/data/types/MealType.js:46:11)"`  and when I use resolve(Meal.FoodItems), it says that foodItems.concat is not a function.

Comment: I just added this bit of code to my main Express server `models.Meal.getFoodItems().then(item => {
 logger.info(JSON.stringify(item), null, 2);
});` and confirmed that for whatever reason, Sequelize isn't creating the getFoodItems function.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I was simply using mock names :) Use whatever you can to get the food items, and same goes to get the recipes

Comment: The purpose here was only to show the GraphQL reasoning, not the sequelize part

Comment: What you need to keep from my answer is that you need to fetch both the `FoodItems` and the `Recipes` and return a merged array to GraphQL